# Is Richardson iteration algorithm backward stable?

Tags: linear-algebra, convergence-divergence, algorithms, stability-theory

How do we analyze the numerical stability of [Richardson iteration algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Richardson_iteration)? Can we say it is  backward stable?